# Trive revo ajax add to cart not working in magento2.1.3

Tags: magento-2.1.3

I am installing Trive revo ajax add to cart plugin in my products, but its not working. It is free Extension.

There is no issue on console or anyfile. When I am clicking the add cart button, the button is changed to adding...

Afterthat, there is no response. Please help me anyone.

Comment: is i t paid or free one ? if paid , contact developers, if free, than post relevant code and update question....